# Replace the two malloc calls by allocating a single buffer and setting list1 and list2 by pointing into that buffer

Tags: c, performance, optimization, buffer

I am using merge sort function and it contains two list using malloc function. In order to increase the performance, I need to replace the two `malloc` calls by allocating a single buffer and setting `list1`
and `list2` by pointing into that buffer. This reduces the number of calls to malloc/free to half.

```
intType* list1 = (intType*)malloc(n1*sizeof(intType));
intType* list2 = (intType*)malloc(n2*sizeof(intType));
```

where `n1 = N /2;`
and `n2 = N -2;`

`N` is the number of elements to be sorted.

I tried different methods but no luck with the implementation. Can someone help here please ?

Comment: "and `n2 = N -2;`": Did you mean "and `n2 = N - n1;`"?

Comment: yes my apologies. Its n2 = N -n1;

Answer (score 2):

You can do that like this:

```
/* allocate buffer for the two arrays */
intType* list1 = malloc((n1 + n2) * sizeof(intType));
/* assign pointer with offset */
intType* list2 = list1 + n1;

/* some works */

free(list1);
```

Also note that casting results of `malloc()` family is [considered as a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: Small note that this only works this easily if both types are the same. If 2 lists would have different alignment requirements, then extra padding may have to be added to make sure second list is correctly aligned.